# execution script for several ID - loop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm downloading ID from localStorage.getItem(1,22,3,14....).
I want every single ID to be executed in jQuery (if it exists on the website).
I can execute the code for one ID, but I don't know what to do to make each ID after the decimal point executed. I try so but it doesn't pass. I have to loop it, right? can anyone help?

```js
var data = "1,22,3,14";
var format_id = data.replace(",", "");   
console.log('id=' +format_id); 

    $("#"+format_id+" .plus").removeClass("plus"); 
    $("#"+format_id+" .1").css("color", "red");
    $("#"+format_id+" .1").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="idkom1">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plus1 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="2" class="idkom2">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plusid2 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>      
</div>

<div id="3" class="idkom3">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plusid3 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you hoping to do with each `id` that you extract from your string?

Comment: `format_id = data.split(',').join(',#')` and change `$("#"+format_id+" .plus")` to `$("#"+format_id+").find(".plus")`

Comment: Lee, thx for format my code. I want to format <div id="x"> as in example.  @Heretic Monkey, big THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split your string into an array using the `split` function.
2. Loop through your ids and process each id in turn.

```js
var data = "1,22,3,14";
let ids = data.split(",");

for(let id of ids)
{
    $("#"+id + " .plus").removeClass("plus"); 
    $("#"+id + " .1").css({"color" : "red", "font-weight": "bold"});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="idkom1">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plus1 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="2" class="idkom2">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plusid2 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>      
</div>

<div id="3" class="idkom3">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plusid3 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Alternative version using a css class

```js
var data = "1,22,3,14";
let ids = data.split(",");

for(let id of ids)
{
    $("#"+id + " .plus").removeClass("plus"); 
    $("#"+id + " .1").addClass("highlight");
}
```

```css
div.highlight
{
  color : red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="idkom1">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plus1 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="2" class="idkom2">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plusid2 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>      
</div>

<div id="3" class="idkom3">
    <a class="punkt plus" href="#">
      <div class="1">plusid3 <i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: beautiful! thank you very much! How can i combine class="1" (color and font-weight) formatting into one line? because that's the only thing I'm missing to be completely happy. I've been sitting on it for a few hours and struggling with google with the gear between PHP and jQuery and already tried split, but I had to break something because it didn't work as it should.

Comment: Please see the edit. Another way to do that would be to add a css class `addClass` to your  element.

Comment: Also, note that using ids with just a number seems to cause a few problems. You'd be better off using more meaningful ids for a real-world scenario.

Comment: no way! I did exactly the same and it didn't work... that's why I did separately. This is not my day! Thanks a lot for your valuable support. Thanks for the note. I will remember.